# Need help converting a list comprehension to a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I am learning lambda functions and I came across a question which is actually meant to be solved using a list comprehension but I wanted to know if there is a way to do the same using lambda functions.

Q - Given a sentence, return the sentence with all it's letters transposed by 1 in the
alphabet, but only if the letter is a-y.

My code using list-comprehension :

```
sentence = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
result = "".join([chr(ord(letter) + 1) if letter != "z" and letter != " " else letter for letter in sentence])
```

This works fine, however the issue is when I try to use lambda functions I can't get the same output. I know that the issue is when the letter is actually "z" or " ", the lambda function ignores that whereas it should just return the same but I do not know how to achieve that.

```
sentence = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
result = "".join(map(lambda y : chr(ord(y) + 1),filter(lambda x : x != "z" and x != " ", sentence)))
```

Expected output = `uif rvjdl cspxo gpy kvnqt pwfs uif mbzz eph`

Output (using lambda) = `uifrvjdlcspxogpykvnqtpwfsuifmbzeph`

Comment: It's much simpler (and more correct) to test for *inclusion* rather than *exclusion*: `''.join(map(lambda letter: chr(ord(letter) + 1) if 'a' <= letter <= 'y' else letter, sentence))`. Note that the question specifies ***a*** sentence, so it should work for all possible inputs, not just one specific example. If the given sentence contains e.g. commas, numbers, capital letters, etc, your current solution won't work properly.

Comment: yes, that's true, I'll keep that in my mind. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not filter out spaces and characters `'z'`, but instead map them to the same characters:

```
result = "".join(map(lambda y : y if y in " z" else chr(ord(y) + 1), sentence))
```

Comment: thank you! I did not actually know you can use `if-else` within lambda functions, the tutorial I was following did not cover it, but that got me thinking, what is the point of using `filter()` then? filter extracts values based on a given condition but you can do that with `map()` too so when do you use each of them?

Comment: You'd use `filter` if you wanted your "out of scope" letters *not to appear in the output at all*, rather than to appear in the output without being converted. In this specific case though (but not all examples of map or filter), you could replicate the effects of `filter` by mapping "out of scope" letters to `''`.

Comment: It's clearer if we look at an example that doesn't use string joins. Let's say you have a sequence of numbers, and the output should contain the squares of the odd numbers only. i.e. input `[3, 4, 6, 7]` should give output `[9, 49]`. That wouldn't be possible using `map` alone.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand,
I can use map even if I want the out of scope letters to not appear in the output at all by doing this right?
`map( lambda y : (do whatever i want with in scope letters) if (condition to check if letter in scope) else None, list)`
This will return an iterable which won't contain the out of scope letters
Also, this should apply to call cases of map or filter I think

Comment: No, that won't work. For example, assuming the letters a-y are in scope, your map would transform `'xyz'` to the sequence `'y', 'z', None`. Then the join operation would fail: attempting `"".join(['y', 'z', None])` gives a TypeError because of the None.